# Passing GET parametrs to .htaccess

Tags: css, .htaccess

I'm trying to minify `css/js` files if there is exists minified `css/js` copy of this file with `.min.` in it's name though `.htaccess`. I'm using following code:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.min.$2 -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.(css|js)$ /$1.min.$2 [L,NC]
```

So, when I go to `/current/assets/css/main.css` I see `/current/assets/css/main.min.css` instead. Is there any way to make it only if I add some GET parametr to url? For example `/current/assets/css/main.css?t=1` gives minified file, but `/current/assets/css/main.css` not. I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.min.$2 -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.(css|js)\?t=[0-9].*$ /$1.min.$2 [L,NC]
```

But it's not working. Guess I mabye should use `%{QUERY_STRING}` but can't get how. Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do that. It was all about `%{QUERY_STRING}`.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^t=([0-9]*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.min.$2 -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.(css|js)$ /$1.min.$2 [L,NC]
```